# One Way Road Trip

Tags: road-trips, shipping

Is it possible to ship a car to a destination in order to drive it back? I would like to take a long road-trip through two or three of the Americas  but wont have the patience to do it twice.

Can I somehow send my car there and drive it back? Does this require special permits? How much does it cost and how long would does the transport take?

Comment: You will most likely have issues with import taxes and duties. It might be easier to do it the other way around (drive it there and ship it back home, provided you can prove the vehicle was original bought there and/or that all taxes and duties were already paid)

Comment: What country are you coming from, and where are you going to?

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but hopefully you're aware that [it's impossible to drive a car overland between Central and South America.](http://www.overlandtraveller.com/destinations/colombia_panama_travel_darien_gap.html)

Comment: Yes, that's why I said 2 or 3 :) There is another question to ferry between Panama or Costa Rica to South America. I don't mind skipping Panama since I've already covered a lot of ground there.

Comment: I'm pretty sure any answer would need your car's origin and destination

Comment: Coming from Canada. Would like to fly it to send it to Central America, not sure which country at this time, depends on what's possible. Based on the one answer, I'm guessing there is no FedEx for Cars :)

Answer (score 2):

Back in 2004/2005 a friend of mine successfully sent a car by rail from Toronto to Vancouver and then back a few months later. There was a company dealing specifically with shipping cars that arranged this, there were a lot of restrictions (e.g. you can have absolutely nothing in the car), but it was possible. I'd imagine there's probably something like this in the US as well. The other option is to just buy a cheap car and either donate or sell it at your final destination.

Comment: Wouldn't happen to remember the name of the company would you ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't remember

Comment: I'd question if such a car would be reliable to drive that distance across unknown countries. Most importantly though, selling car into another country sounds like it would require quite a bit of paper work on its own.