# What's the cheapest way of doing a one-way USA road trip?

Tags: usa, budget, road-trips, one-way

My partner and I are planning a road trip from North Carolina, USA to California, USA starting in September and finishing in December. We were thinking of buying a car when we get there, then selling it at the other end but are unsure about Tax/Insurance/MOT etc in USA. Hiring a car seems quite pricey for three months (cheapest we can find is about $1,000).

What would be the best way of doing this?

Comment: Hi and welcome. The cheapest way of doing this is most probably by hitch-hiking. However this might not be compatible with your style of travel. Since best and cheapest are subjective criteria, [we don't really deal with these questions on Travel.SE](http://travel.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Try reading the Help Centre to get a better understanding of how this site work and then edit the question to make it answerable.

Comment: By far the cheapest way is **hiring a car**.  Do that.

Comment: Jo, the question very obviously means cheapest way to "get a car" for a road trip.  This is an excellent question - although I believe it has been asked a number of times.

Comment: Buying a car in the US, registering it as a non-resident, titling it as a non resident, and obtaining insurance as a non-resident, will cost you more than 1000 USD. It will probably also take you a few weeks to a month to obtain all the necessary paperwork after purchasing the vehicle.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [One Way Road Trip](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/61841/one-way-road-trip)

Comment: aw man!  it got closed before I click "send" on my answer  :)

Comment: not that it matters but the idea that this question was closed as "opinion based" is batty

Comment: Since you mentioned California, you will also need Liability insurance in that state. $1000 is on the low end of the spectrum, I think it's going to cost you atleast 3 or 4 times more than that.

Comment: Do you have auto coverage at home that might cover your driving in the US?